# Suppose $T \in L(V)$ and $V = nullT + rangeT$. Show that the sum is direct.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

My thoughts are to show that if $x \in nullT$ and $y \in rangeT$ then if $0=x+y$ we must have that $x,y=0$.

So far my logic is the following:

$0=x+y$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(0)=T(x+y)$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(0)=T(x)+T(y)$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(0)=T(y)$.

Now I know this would show that $y=0$ if we knew that T was injective however how do we know that T is injective simply from the fact that $V=nullT+rangeT$? I was wondering if there is some way to play with dimension to show that $nullityT=0$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the rank nullity theorem?

Comment: @angryavian yes. I was thinking about that but how do we know that $rankT = dimV$?

Comment: Are you assuming $V$ is finite dimensional? If not, consider $V=\mathcal{l}^2$ and $$T(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_2,x_3,...)$$ This is a surjective linear operator with $$N(T)=\text{span}\{(1,0,...)\}$$ So, $$V=R(T)+N(T)$$ $$R(T)\cap N(T)=N(T)\neq \{\vec{0}\}$$ This sum isn't direct.

Comment: @MatthewH. Sorry I should have specified. V is finite dimensional.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638049/need-help-let-t-v-rightarrow-v-if-v-is-finite-dimensional-and-v-nullt same question

Comment: You ask how we know that $\mathop{\rm rank}(T)=\dim(V)$ in this situation. The answer to that is that we don't, since it's false in general. @MatthewH's comment shows that we must assume $V$ is finite dimensional. What does rank-nullity say? How is it connected to whether the sum is direct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by contrapositive which doesn't use any results.

Suppose we can find some nonzero $w_0 \in \ker T \  \cap \text{im } T $.

Now let $Tw_1 =w_0$ for some $w_1 \in \text{im T}$. [If $w_1 \notin \text{im }T$, then since $V = \ker T + \text{im }T$, we can write $w_1 = w_1' + w_1''$ with $w_1' \in \ker T$, $w_1'' \in \text{im }T$ and since then $w_0 = Tw_1 = Tw_1''$, we can take $w_1''$ instead of $w_1$].

Similarly we can find $w_2 \in \text{im }T$ s.t. $Tw_2 = w_1$. Continuing with this process, consider the equation

$$\sum_{i=0}^n c_iw_i = 0 \tag 1$$

wherein $Tw_{i} = w_{i-1}$ for $i > 0$ and $Tw_0 = 0$. Applying the operator $T^n$ to $(1)$ we obtain $c_nw_0 = 0$ implying that $c_n = 0$. We can then apply $T^{n-1}$ to see $c_{n-1} = 0$ and so on. So $c_i = 0 \ \forall i$.

Thus $\{w_i\}_{i=0}^n$ is linearly independent. Since $n$ was arbitrary, this contradicts finite dimensionality of $V$.

$\square$